# How to align span text and input element horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am working on creating a search form. With this search form, I was using an `<input>` tag. Right beside the search bar, I would like to have a word of a text that reads " SEARCH DEFINITION ". At the moment my Search Definition text in a span tag is not horizontally centered to the search bar.

I've attempted to handle this by adding `padding-top: 15px;` which gets me a similar to look what I am going for. Is this something that is possible with a css property? I've attempted using `display: inline-block;` but it did not have an effect.

[image]

My expected outcome is to have the text `SEARCH DEFINITION` appear side by side with the search bar and aligned horizontally to the center of the search bar. Similar to this photo:

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code:

```css
.background {
  background-color:gray;
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
}


span {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="background">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 padding-top"> 
    <span class="text-bold-white-14">SEARCH DEFINITION </span>
  </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <i class="fas search fa-search"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Keyword">
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
            
            
        </div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add one class to your `.row` div, the class is `.align-items-center`, since row has display property set to flex by bootstrap, you already have it as a flex. So to align them vertically centered just add above class in the row div like this:

```html
<div class="row align-items-center">
</div>
```

and by adding class `text-right` to span's parent element make the text "SEARCH DEFINITION" aligned to the right side.

Here's working code:

```css
.background {
    background-color:gray;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}


span {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

input {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="background">


<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-4 padding-top text-right"> 
    <span class="text-bold-white-14">SEARCH DEFINITION </span>
  </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <i class="fas search fa-search"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Keyword">
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
            
            
        </div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `d-flex` class to the row to align it vertically.

```
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center"> 
  //...
</div>
```

Then `text-right` class to the div containing `span`

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-right"> 
    <span class="text-bold-white-14">SEARCH DEFINITION </span>
  </div>
```

```css
.background {
  background-color:gray;
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
}


span {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="background">


<div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-right"> 
    <span class="text-bold-white-14">SEARCH DEFINITION </span>
  </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <i class="fas search fa-search"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Keyword">
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
            
            
        </div>
        
</div>
```