# How to horizontally align text of input-field to that of a neighbouring element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Dear stack**overflow** community,

I'm looking for a clean way to (horizontally) align the text of an element to that of an angular-material input field.

When using the following code:

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>Hello: </div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput value="world"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I end up with something like this:

[image]

I need the text of the div, or that of any other element, to be aligned. So, what I am looking for, is something like this:

[image]

#### Main question

How should I go about aligning the two?

#### Bonus question

The default alignment is quite far off. Do I want something strange here? Am I trying to achieve something fundamentally wrong, or is aligning them 'manually' something everybody does?

#### Possibly related question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65244514/how-to-align-span-text-and-input-element-horizontally) could be related, since the problem is quite similar. But the provided code is, at least for me, too different to extract a possible solution for my question.

Thanks in advance,

Wouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had received a nice answer to my question, however, for some reason it has been removed. I will therefore attempt to repeat what I took from it.

---

In essence, all you need to do is align the items of your flexbox. Adding `align-items:baseline` will do the trick if you want to align the items in the flexbox by their text.

Like this:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: baseline">
  <div>Hello: </div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput value="world"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Or, as per the previously posted answer:

```
#box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```
<div id = "box">
  <div>Hello: </div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput value="world"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

For more information, take a look at [this website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-properties). It is a comprehensive guide for anything you need to know about the flexbox.